# Use XML parser for rss XML text file which is store in Edit Text field

Tags: java, android

I want to read XML file which is store in `editTextxml.setText(xml)`.
In that rss xml tags are there and i want to use XML parser to display this tags.

view-source:http://syndication.indianexpress.com/rss/latest-news.xml

```
  public class XmlDownloader extends Activity {

    LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;

    InputStream in;

    String xml;// = onGet
                // ("http://syndication.indianexpress.com/rss/latest-news.xml");
    Button downloadxml;
    Button parsingXML;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.xmldownloader);

        downloadxml = (Button) findViewById(R.id.downloadxml);
        final EditText editTextxml = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextXml);
        parsingXML = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ParsingXMLData);

        downloadxml.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                onGet("http://syndication.indianexpress.com/rss/latest-news.xml");

                Log.d("test", xml);

                editTextxml.setText(xml);
            }

        });

    }

    private String onGet(String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        /* String result = null; */

        HttpResponse response;
        HttpEntity entity;

        try {

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            response = httpClient.execute(httppost);

            entity = response.getEntity();

            if (entity != null) {

                InputStream is = entity.getContent();

                if (is != null) {

                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    String line;

                    try {

                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8 * 1024);
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(line); // .append("\n");
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        is.close();
                    }
                    xml = sb.toString();
                }
                entity.consumeContent();
            }
            httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        return xml;
    }
```

I want to use `editTextxml.setText(xml)` to get XML parsing in another Button
What is the XML parsing for this code

Comment: Why no go through http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

Comment: Try to use AsyncTask : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: i store xml file in edit view... and i want to use that in another button(Button parsingXML) functon as input how can i Do that???